# Virtual Host HTTPS redirection in AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, virtualhost

Am having two domains abc.example.com and xyz.example.com. I got SSL certificate for *.example.com from AWS (where i can't download SSL certificate).Am using Virtual host file for pointing two domains to two different folder /var/www/html/abc and /var/www/html/xyz. Now I want to use Redirect from http to https for both the domains in virtual host.I tried virtual host code something like this:

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
    ServerName abc.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://abc.example.com/
    ServerAlias www.abc.example.com
< /VirtualHost >   
< VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://xyz.example.com/
    ServerAlias www.xyz.example.com
< /VirtualHost >
```

And also tried *:443 instead of *:80. But I couldn't get any results.
Please Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"But I couldn't get any results"* is not a sufficient description of how your attempts are failing to work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

After spending lots of hour , finally found a solution for the problem.
The code works in this way:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
    ServerName abc.example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/abc">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php   
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/xyz">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php   
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront can redirect to HTTP to HTTPS for you automatically:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But am not using cloud front. Is it possible in another way?

Comment: Hard to say what's the problem there but you probably need 2 certificates (one for example.com and other for *.example.com) if you want to catch all subdomains and the zone apex.